# APA Citation. I don't know what it's considered as

Tags: citations, citation-style

My professor gave me a pdf to cite in another paper I have. I don't know if I consider it as a report, article, or paper. I included the cite of the pdf my professor gave me. Please let me know how to cite this in APA style. Thanks!

http://www.seattleaudubon.org/sas/Portals/0/Conservation/Regional/WSDOT%202011_SR520%20Wetland%20Mitigtion%20Plan_UBNA%20section.pdf

This is the link, and all I have to work with.

Answer (score 2):

I found the following information in the document's footer (last few lines on each page):

- Date: December 2011
- Title: "I-5 to Medina: Bridge Replacement and HOV Project 
  Final Wetland Mitigation Report"
- Type of Document: Report

Googling this information yields the author, namely the [Washington State Department of Transportation, SR 520 Bridge Replacement and HOV Program](https://www.wsdot.wa.gov/Projects/SR520Bridge/), and the location, which is Seattle, WA. In this case, the author is also the publisher (although I would omit the part after the comma).

I leave it to you as an exercise to compile this information into an [APA citation](http://www.easybib.com/guides/citation-guides/apa-format/how-to-cite-a-report-apa/).